# How do I use SQL column values as column names in Oracle 11

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have an table something like:

```
    Date     |  Communication_Type
   ----------  --------------------
   12/10/2011  EMAIL
   12/10/2011  WEB
   12/10/2011  WEB
   11/10/2011  MAIL
   11/10/2011  FAX
   11/10/2011  FAX
   11/10/2011  EMAIL
```

I want to write a query to display the top two communication types for a certain date, but the communication types are not limited to the ones shown here, they could be one of 100.

Is there a way I could get an output like this, ie for the 11/11/2011

```
<_top_communication_type_count> | <second_top_communication_type_count>
-------------------------------- --------------------------------------
2                                1
```

where _top_communication_type_count would be the `FAX_COUNT` in this instance, but for the `12/11/2011` would be `WEB_COUNT`

Its a bit difficult to explain but hopefully you get what I mean!
I've found examples for mySQL, but not for Oracle.

Comment: Please show the mySQL version (and what error do you get using it?)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to use a list of unknown values as column names in Oracle (10g does have `pivot` but it requires a known list of values). In theory you could do it by querying for unique values first, then building a dynamic query, but it would be a lot of work for marginally useful results.

Below is a solution that returns the data in a normal row-based format (based on @Michael Durrant's answer, modified to work in Oracle):

```
select *
from   (
   select communication_type
   from   communications c
   where  date = 'the_date'
   order  by count(c.communication_type)
   group  by c.communication_type)
where rownum <= 2
```